# Creating a Survey/Poll including divs, once submitted, show percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Other than HTML and CSS, I am still learning additional computer languages. I am looking to include an interactive poll on my webpage. There are four divs on my webpage. Each div consists of an image, title and content related to a specific type of product. The idea is to allow consumers to click "their favorite" product, which will then do a couple of things. First, it will add an overlay to the other three divs to prevent them from clicking the other divs; From another question on here, I found this could use the javascript attribute "disable" to the three divs NOT selected. Second, I was hoping it's possible to somehow keep track of these choices and display the percentage of picks for each product on top of each of the four divs.

I have searched multiple different phrases both in this site and via Google and found a number of free poll websites, but I'm really looking for the above feature(s) if they are possible and easy enough to implement. I have come across http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element which sort of does what I'm envisioning for the overlay with text. If you click Block with Message, that is pretty much what I'm looking for but instead of Processing... the percentage of clicks for that div in comparison with total clicks would show.

The four divs all have the similar HTML and CSS markup:

```
<div class="col-lg-3" align="center"><img src="images/golden.png" /><br /><h5>Golden with Delicate Taste</h5><h6>Usually made at the beginning of the new maple season. Pour over vanilla ice cream for a maple sundae.</h6></div>
```

CSS for the col-lg-3 and font tags are roughly the same per screen resolution:

```
width: 25%; position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; float: left;
```

As you can see, it is related to Maple Syrup. There are four flavors of maple syrup we want to allow users to pick their favorite, as mentioned above. I do have a Wufoo account but it doesn't really allow us to customize the forms/polls enough to get a very interactive poll. If I can someone integrate that poll with custom language, that would be awesome!

As I have not found any specific answers via Google Search, I'm thinking this may not be possible at least with my knowledge. I figured I'd post a question on here to pick your brains. I do not expect anyone to do the work but any suggestions on if this is possible and/or what language or tools to use, that would be great! If you can provide hints, that would help as well!

Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'd guess that this is a huge project. You'll need a server to store the data, a way to read the user IP, store it so that they can't vote 100 times, and a variety of other issues. Have you looked at SurveyMonkey?

Comment: That's what I was thinking but was looking for expert confirmation and/or suggestions considering other languages such as javascript, ajax, etc. Yes, SurveyMonkey and Wufoo. My team and I prefer not to push the user to a separate page, and if the results load in an iframe it cuts off some of the reporting page - as it's trying to load an entire page in a smaller iframe. I've confirmed with Wufoo that it cannot load widgets only. The entire page is being displayed.